# Why doens't IPv6 display client IP name like IPv4 does?

Tags: python, ipv6

Hi there sorry for disturbing you guys. But I read something in the Magazine about porting codes to IPV6 so i tried just changing this code (socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

In python it works, but the problem is that the server does not display the client ip.

I expected it to display it like this. Got connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59815).

But for it , it messes up all thing and give me this (Got connection from ('::1', 59815, 0, 0)),
So if I ask were is the client IP here?. and what does the two last zeros(0, 0) really mean?. And what should i do to port my code to IPv6.? Thanks iam using python(geany)

So if I do this(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) will I have put my code to IPV6, o are there some other things I need to do thanks)

Comment: `::1` _is_ the local host IPv6 ip-address.

Answer (score 9):

`::1` is the IPv6 address for localhost, just like `127.0.0.1` is the IPv4 address for localhost. So you *are* seeing the client's IPv6 address.

The fields in the socket address are documented in the [Python `socket` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html). They are:

- host
- port
- flowinfo
- scope-id

Flowinfo and scope-id are new for IPv6. Flowinfo contains the Flow Label, which is specified in [RFC 6437](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6437). If you don't know how to use it you can safely leave it at `0`. The scope-id is used when an address is valid in multiple scopes. IPv6 [link-local addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) for example are valid on every IPv6 interface, but routing them from one interface to another is not possible. So if you want to communicate with link-local addresses you have to specify which interface to use. The scope-id is the number of the interface.

When porting code to IPv6 you have to think about a few things. The socket handling you already have changed. You should also look at name resolving and use functions that support both IPv4 and IPv6 (i.e. don't use [gethostbyname()](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname) but use [getaddrinfo()](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) etc.) And don't forget to allocate enough space when storing IP addresses. IPv6 addresses take up more space than IPv4 addresses.

PS: The [IPy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy/) library provides very useful classes for dealing with IP addresses.